# Slave duplicate counter

Tags: counters

Is it possible to create a counter that is a "slave" to another (master) counter, but also an exact duplicate?

The `\@addtoreset{<slave>}{<master>}` resets `<slave>` whenever `<master>` is incremented (similar functionality is offered by [`chngcntr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/chngcntr)), but I don't know about anything incrementing one counter (`<slave>`) automatically whenever another counter (`<master>`) is incremented.

The idea is to have a macro (say) `\dupcntr{<slave>}{<master>}` as an analogue to `\@addtoreset`. The application for this might be where one is interested in renaming a counter used/provided by a package into something more meaningful for the user (say, `<slave>`), without having to reference `<master>`. Or, if the original counter contains `@` that needs to be escaped every time it's used, it is sometimes more convenient to have a "more user friendly" counter.

I know one way around is to use a macro that returns the value of `<master>`, but is it possible to perform the same manipulation with a macro than one could with the counter? Manipulation here refers to the printing of the counter (via `\the<slave>`) and perhaps it's representation (like `\arabic`, `\alph`, ...).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If both should have always the same value, why not simply `\let` the slave to the master? This copies the internal reference to the `\count` register.

```
\newcommand*{\dupcntr}[2]{%
    \expandafter\let\csname c@#1\expandafter\endcsname\csname c@#2\endcsname
}
```

This is for LaTeX counters. For TeX count's simply remove the `c@` (if given by cs name) or use `\let#1#2` if given by control sequence.

Comment: You have to copy also `\themaster` into `\theslave`; of course, redefining `\themaster` wouldn't redefine `\theslave`, nor conversely.

Comment: @egreg: True. I would say `\newcommand\theslave{\themaster}` should do it.

Answer (score 7):

Check out my "amsthm tweaks": [posted here](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~ryanr/index.php?page=latex&subpage=rrthm).  I did just this, because the `amsthm` package is lazy about making subordinate theorem numbers, and this breaks the `fncylab` package's way of customizing `\ref`'s output.  The code is thus:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\clonecounter}[2]{
  \@xp\xdef\csname c@#1\endcsname{\@xp\@nx\csname c@#2\endcsname}
  \@xp\xdef\csname the#1\endcsname{\@xp\@nx\csname the#2\endcsname}
  % This is for hyperref compatibility
  \@xp\xdef\csname theH#1\endcsname{\@xp\@nx\csname theH#2\endcsname}
  % Don't copy p@#2 or cl@#2!
  \global\@xp\let\csname p@#1\endcsname = \@empty
  \global\@xp\let\csname cl@#1\endcsname = \@empty
  % This is wrong, for some reason.  So it's commented out.
  %\@addtoreset{#1}{@ckpt}
 }
\makeatother
```

This makes a new counter `#1` which, at its birth, is a complete slave to `#2`: same count register, same manner of printing.  It sets up all the internal quantities that LaTeX considers to constitute a "counter", so you can `\addtocounter` and `\refstepcounter` and `\@addtoreset` correctly.

Answer (score 6):

Heiko Oberdiek's [`aliascnt` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/aliascnt) provides this functionality. It provides `\newaliascnt{<slave>}{<master>}` and can be used in instances where theorems share base counters:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{aliascnt}% http://ctan.org/pkg/aliascnt
\newtheorem{foo}{Foo}% counter "foo"
\newaliascnt{bar}{foo}% alias counter "bar"
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% Just for this example
\begin{document}
\setcounter{foo}{10}%
\begin{foo}Something\end{foo}
\verb|foo:|\ \thefoo \par
\verb|bar:|\ \thebar
\end{document}
```

As expected, it integrates well with [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref).

Answer (score 3):

ConTeXt presents a key-value interface to couple two counters. For example:

```
\definecounter
  [first]
  [numberconversion=Characters]

\definecounter
  [second]
  [number=first, numberconversion=numbers]

\starttext

\incrementcounter[first]
\incrementcounter[first]

\convertedcounter[first] % Prints "B"
\convertedcounter[second]% Prints "2"

\stoptext
```

If you want the second counter to inherit all the settings of the first counter, (conversion, color, style, etc), just use

```
\definecounter
   [second]
   [first]
```

Answer (score 3):

The package [`assoccnt`](http://ctan.org/pkg/assoccnt) and its successor [`xassoccnt`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xassoccnt) provides exactly this feature, "a way of associating counters to an existing driver counter so that incrementing the driver counter will increase its associated counters as well."

Here is a small example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{assoccnt}
\newcounter{mysection}
\DeclareAssociatedCounters{section}{mysection}

\begin{document}

\thesection\ \themysection

\section{A section} \thesection\ \themysection

\end{document}
```

Comment: (+1) for mentioning `xassoccnt`, but please don't use `assoccnt` any longer. It had some issues which are hopefully extinguished in `xassoccnt`. I will soon declare `assoccnt` as obsolete