# How to enumerate figures in sync with another counter?

Tags: floats, counters

I when I create a command for (for example) the examples in my article, I do it in this way:

```
\newtheorem{teo}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{ex}[teo]{Example}
```

So the enumeration is consecuent to what I have done with the theorems and other things, but the figures do their own enumeration, how can I change that in the same way of the examples? Thanks

Comment: Exactly, for example, if there is a figure between theorem 2.3, and example 2.4, I want them to be, theorem 2.3, figure 2.4, and example 2.5

Comment: Did you see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/327384/5001) to the query [Numbering figures](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/56574/5001)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can essentially use the same approach as in your MWE except that you use `figure` to number your theorems:

```
\numberwithin{figure}{section}% number figures inside sections
\newtheorem{teo}[figure]{Theorem}
\newtheorem{ex}[figure]{Example}
```

The `\numberwithin` command, which comes from `amsmath`, numbers the figures in tandem with the sections. Using this approach you can get the output

[image]

using the code:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\numberwithin{figure}{section}
\newtheorem{teo}[figure]{Theorem}
\newtheorem{ex}[figure]{Example}

\begin{document}

\section{Let the section begin}

  \begin{teo}The sum of two numbers is a number\label{T:one}\end{teo}

  \begin{figure}[h]A figure\caption{Nice one}\label{F:one}\end{figure}

  \begin{ex}For example, $1+2=3$.\label{E:one}\end{ex}

  See \ref{T:one}, \ref{F:one} and \ref{E:one}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: This answer depends on the use of the `amsart` document class.  But that's not necessary -- `article` plus `amsthm` gives the same result.

Comment: @barbarabeeton As the OP didn't provide a MWE with a document class I took the liberty of using my preferred article class, which is `amsart`. Using `article` and `amsthm` does not work as this gives an "Undefined control sequence" error for `\numberwithin`. Of course, you could use `\makeatletter\@addtoreset{figure}{section}\makeatother` with the `article` document class.

Comment: Ah!  Forgot that.  Easily fixed -- `\usepackage{amsmath}`.  (Rash assumption -- if one is using `amsthm`, one is probably already using `amsmath`.  Nice to hear that `amsart` is your favorite, but not everyone has the same preferences.)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that employs the [xassoccnt](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/assoccnt) package to couple the `teo` and `figure` counters.

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{teo}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{ex}[teo]{Example}

\usepackage{xassoccnt}
\DeclareCoupledCounters[name=figurteo]{figure,teo}
\renewcommand\thefigure{\thesection.\arabic{figure}}

% just to allow 4 floats on a page:
\setcounter{totalnumber}{4}
\setcounter{topnumber}{4}

\begin{document}

% just for this example
\setcounter{chapter}{2}
\setcounter{section}{3}

\begin{teo}In the beginning, \dots \end{teo}
\begin{teo}After a while, \dots\end{teo}
\begin{figure}[ht]\caption{Fee}\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[ht]\caption{Fi}\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[ht]\caption{Fo}\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[ht]\caption{Fum}\end{figure}
\begin{ex}And then, \dots\end{ex}
\begin{ex}Finally, \dots\end{ex}

\end{document}
```