# Adjusting the gb4e {exe} environment locally

Tags: horizontal-alignment, lists, indentation, linguistics, gb4e

In my thesis I make extensive use of the `exe` environment of the `gb4e`package and I love it. However, three of my approximately 100 examples need to have an alternative layout. Instead of the usual design I need the second and the following lines of these three examples to start where the opening bracket of the `exe` environment starts. So, ideally, in (1) the *bdfs* line and in (2) the *bdfs* and the *cdfs* line start where the opening bracket starts. Does anyone know how to locally generate this variation?

[image]

This is created with the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}%dt.Silbentrennung

\usepackage{gb4e}

\begin{document}

\begin{exe}
\ex asdf asdf

bsdf bsdf % ideally, this line starts where the opening bracket starts
\ex asdf asdf

bsdf bsdf % ideally, this line starts where the opening bracket starts

csdf csdf % ideally, this line starts where the opening bracket starts
\end{exe}
\end{document}
```

Edditional note: As Alan Munn highlighted in a comment the numbering in linguistics is continuously starting with 1. Therefore, the command / environment needs to be numbered according to its position. It has to be sensitive for previous examples and the following examples need to be sensitive to the command / environment.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`gb4e`](http://ctan.org/pkg/gb4e) sets the `exe` environment as a regular `list`. Moreover, every `\ex` macro defaults to `\item` (if you don't specify an optional argument). So, you can use [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) to emulate the display, yet set some other properties as needed.

The following MWE does exactly that (I grabbed the list parameters from [`g4be.sty`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/gb4e/gb4e.sty)) and provides `myexe` as the alternative:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{gb4e,enumitem,calc}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{gb4e,enumitem,calc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\newlist{myexe}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[myexe]{
  label=(\arabic*),
  labelindent=*,
  leftmargin=1em,
  labelwidth=\widthof{(234)},
  labelsep=1em,
  itemindent=\labelindent+\labelwidth,
  topsep=7pt plus 2pt minus 3pt,
  itemsep=3pt plus 2pt,
  listparindent=0pt,
  parsep=1pt plus.5pt minus.5pt
  }
\makeatletter
\let\c@myexei\c@exx% http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33898/5764
\patchcmd{\enit@enumerate@i}% <cmd>
  {\usecounter\@enumctr}% <search>
  {\@nmbrlisttrue\def\@listctr{\@enumctr}}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\makeatother
\begin{document}

Original \verb|exe| environment:

\begin{exe}
\ex asdf asdf

bsdf bsdf % ideally, this line starts where the opening bracket starts
\ex asdf asdf

bsdf bsdf% ideally, this line starts where the opening bracket starts

csdf csdf % ideally, this line starts where the opening bracket starts
\end{exe}

Updated \verb|myexe| environment:

\begin{myexe}
\ex asdf asdf

bsdf bsdf % ideally, this line starts where the opening bracket starts
\ex asdf asdf

bsdf bsdf % ideally, this line starts where the opening bracket starts

csdf csdf % ideally, this line starts where the opening bracket starts
\end{myexe}

\end{document}
```

The [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) patch (to be placed *after* defining `myexe`) is required to make `myexe` fit with the rest of the `exe` environments used by `gb4e` and allows for sequential numbering of each example.

`\newlist{<list>}{<type>}{<depth>}` creates a list `<list>` that is of type `<type>` and has depth `<depth>`, almost like cloning the list. `\setlist{<list>}{<options>}` sets global options for the list `<list>` that avoid setting them locally at every usage, as in

```
\begin{myexe}[<options>]
  %...
\end{myexe}
```

For more on global list settings, see section **5 Global settings** (p 9) of the [`enumitem` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/enumitem.pdf).

Comment: First time I see a `setlist` so elaborate. This is very interesting.

Comment: @azetina: I've added some detail.

Comment: For linguists, it is essential to also add ``resume=exe`` to the keylist to continue enumeration of the examples throughout the document.

Comment: This has the disadvantage of needing to replace *all* of the examples with this environment, which is not really practical.

Comment: @AlanMunn: The OP mentioned that s/he has 3 out of 100 that requires a different layout. Hardly a global requirement. Moreover, if need be, one can replace `exe` to use `myexe`. I don't have enough experience with usage of [`g4be`](http://ctan.org/pkg/g4be) to advocate that.

Comment: @Werner What I meant was that to use this environment along with regular examples you need a way to harmonize the numbering, since linguistic examples are sequentially numbered throughout the document. (e.g. try the following environments in order `{exe} {exe} {myexe} \item \item {exe}.` The correct numbering should be (1) (2) (3) (4) (5).

Comment: @AlanMunn: I think I fixed the problem...

Comment: @Werner Yes, that seems to fix it.

Comment: Thanks, Werner! When I changed the `labelsep` to 0 it worked. But there is a minor problem. When I "built" the preamble with `\usepackage{gb4e,enumitem,calc}`, `myexe` and "the following patch" I didnt get the continuous numbering Alan Munn pointed out. Currently, `myexe` affects the following numbers of ´exe´, but it is not affected  by ´exe´ nor by previous ´myexe´. Each ´myexe´ starts with number 1. However,  ´myexe` needs to be numbered according to its position. Is there a way to make it fit, e.g. being sensitive for previous and following ´exe´ and ´myexe´ (without manual adjustment)?

Comment: @Philip: At the bottom of my answer I added the code that you need to insert in the preamble to correct for this. Did you try it?

Comment: If the counter `exx` is greater than 9, then the label of `myexe` is printed differently from its `exe` counterpart. I think you should delete `align=left`.

Comment: @karlkoeller: Absolutely correct.

Comment: @Werner, somehow I missed it. Now it works. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 9):

A completely different approach from Werner's one.

Load `calc` package and add

```
\makeatletter
\def\myex{\setlength{\parindent}{-\leftmargin+\labelsep}\@ifnextchar [{\@ex}{\item}}
\makeatother
```

in the preamble.

Then use the newly defined `\myex` inside the `exe` environments where you want the special layout, e.g.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}%dt.Silbentrennung

\usepackage{gb4e,calc}

\makeatletter
\def\myex{\setlength{\parindent}{-\leftmargin+\labelsep}\@ifnextchar [{\@ex}{\item}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\noindent Usual layout: 
\begin{exe}
\ex asdf asdf

bsdf bsdf % ideally, this line starts where the opening bracket starts
\ex asdf asdf

bsdf bsdf % ideally, this line starts where the opening bracket starts

csdf csdf % ideally, this line starts where the opening bracket starts
\end{exe}

\noindent Modified layout:
\begin{exe}
\myex asdf asdf

bsdf bsdf % ideally, this line starts where the opening bracket starts
\myex asdf asdf

bsdf bsdf % ideally, this line starts where the opening bracket starts

csdf csdf % ideally, this line starts where the opening bracket starts
\end{exe}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Otherwise, you can simply add a line

```
\setlength{\parindent}{-\leftmargin+\labelsep}
```

just after `\begin{exe}` when you want the special layout.

---

Of course, with this approach, items after the nineth will look like

[image]

If you don't like this behavior, you can substitute the above code between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` with the following one:

```
\newlength{\digitlen}
\settowidth{\digitlen}{1}

\makeatletter
\def\myex{%
\ifnum\thexnumi>8%
  \ifnum\thexnumi>98%
    \setlength{\parindent}{-\leftmargin+\labelsep-2\digitlen}%
  \else%
    \setlength{\parindent}{-\leftmargin+\labelsep-\digitlen}%
  \fi%
\else%
  \setlength{\parindent}{-\leftmargin+\labelsep}%
\fi%
\@ifnextchar [{\@ex}{\item}}
\makeatother
```

Thus, the following MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}%dt.Silbentrennung

\usepackage{gb4e,calc}

\newlength{\digitlen}
\settowidth{\digitlen}{1}

\makeatletter
\def\myex{%
\ifnum\thexnumi>8%
  \ifnum\thexnumi>98%
    \setlength{\parindent}{-\leftmargin+\labelsep-2\digitlen}%
  \else%
    \setlength{\parindent}{-\leftmargin+\labelsep-\digitlen}%
  \fi%
\else%
  \setlength{\parindent}{-\leftmargin+\labelsep}%
\fi%
\@ifnextchar [{\@ex}{\item}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\setcounter{exx}{8}

\begin{exe}
\myex asdf asdf

bsdf bsdf % ideally, this line starts where the opening bracket starts
\myex asdf asdf

bsdf bsdf % ideally, this line starts where the opening bracket starts

csdf csdf % ideally, this line starts where the opening bracket starts
\end{exe}

\setcounter{exx}{98}

\begin{exe}
\myex asdf asdf

bsdf bsdf % ideally, this line starts where the opening bracket starts
\myex asdf asdf

bsdf bsdf % ideally, this line starts where the opening bracket starts

csdf csdf % ideally, this line starts where the opening bracket starts
\end{exe}

\end{document}
```

yields

[image]

Comment: This is a reasonable idea. It would make more sense to create a new `\myex` version so that you don't redefine `\ex` for all the other examples.

Comment: @AlanMunn Indeed. I didn't read the question accurately (I was going to sleep...). I'll modify the answer.

Comment: @karlkoeller, thank you so much! Your solution works perfectly well. However, the reason why I checked Werners solution is that I understand some of it (even though it is a just tiny little bit) so I can do minor adjustments myself and maybe some day I can apply it to other problems.