# How to make specific equations follow theorem counter

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, theorems

I don't want equations to be numbered in general, but I want to be able to reference specific equations and have them follow the theorem counter. For instance, in my example there are two equations within theorem 1.1, and I want the first one to be labeled 1.2 so I can reference it in the proof.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]

\begin{document}
    \section{Section}
    \begin{theorem}
        We have some equations
        \begin{align*}
        \label{first}
            1 + 1 = 2,
        \end{align*}
        and
        \begin{align*}
            2 + 2 = 4.
        \end{align*}
    \end{theorem}
    \begin{proof}
        See \ref{first}.
    \end{proof}
    \begin{theorem}
        I want this counter to be 1.3
    \end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You could use the `aliascnt` package.

Comment: since you're using `amsthm` you can set the theorem counter to use the equation counter: `\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[equation]`.  this is documented in the `amsthm` users guide (`texdoc amsthm`) with an explanation of how theorem numbering works.  since you also want the theorems numbered by section, the obvious approach is then to number the equations by section: `\numberwithin{equation}{section}`.

Comment: You're interested in this: [Slave duplicate counter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33898/5764) (possible duplicate)

Comment: @Werner No, it's a different problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

since you're using `amsthm` you can set the theorem counter to use the equation counter:

```
\newtheorem{theorem}[equation]{Theorem}
```

this is documented in the `amsthm` users guide (`texdoc amsthm`) with an explanation of how theorem numbering works.

you have edited the question so that theorems are numbered by section.
this should produce the result you say you want.  since equations (all
displays, actually) have the primary counter, there shouldn't be any
confusion if you have numbered displays that are *not* within theorems.

a full example follows.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
%\usepackage{cleveref}

\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\newtheorem{theorem}[equation]{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\section{Section}

\begin{theorem}\label{firsttheorem}
We have some equations
\begin{equation}\label{equation}
1 + 1 = 2,
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation*}
2 + 2 = 4.
\end{equation*}
\end{theorem}
\begin{proof}
See \ref{equation}.
\end{proof}

\begin{theorem}\label{secondtheorem}
I want this counter to be 1.3
\end{theorem}

%References: \Cref{firsttheorem}, \Cref{secondtheorem}
%and \Cref{equation}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

if the commented lines about `cleveref` are uncommented, the output will be as follows.

[image]