# Appendix uniform Figure numbering

Tags: appendices

I'm currently working on my Thesis and I am trying to get my Appendix sorted. 
here is my Appendix code:

```
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Appendix}
\renewcommand{\tablename}{Appendix}
\setcounter{figure}{0}
\setcounter{table}{0}
\renewcommand\thefigure{\thesection.\roman{figure}}  
\renewcommand\thetable{\thesection.\roman{table}} 
\pagestyle{plain}
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\setcounter{page}{1}
```

Currently it is producing Figure titles like so;

> Appendix 5.i:

And treats tables and figures separately, which I would like to avoid.
Ideally, I'd like an appendix with continuous numbering despite tables or figures.

Any idea how to do that?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us a bit more about the (desired) structure of the appendix material. E.g., does this material consist mainly (exclusively?) of tables and figures? Since you're resetting both `\figurename` and `\tablename`, is there even a point in using both `figure` and `table` environments? Put differently, why not use just `table` (or `figure`) environments? Please advise.

Comment: Off-topic: the `\pagenumbering` instruction resets the `page` counter variable; no need to issue a separate `\setcounter{page}{1}` instruction.

Comment: Hi,thanks for the quick response, I am using both Figure (pictures) and Table environments.

Comment: Even simpler, use either figure or table but not both.  The only difference between figure and table is the caption.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `table` and `figure` counters are supposed to move together, it's best to make one counter a duplicate of the other. This may be achieved, e.g., with the `\dupcntr` macro provided in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/33901/5001) provided by Martin Scharrer.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Appendix}
\renewcommand{\tablename}{Appendix}
\setcounter{figure}{0}
\setcounter{table}{0}
\renewcommand\thefigure{\thesection.\roman{figure}}  
\renewcommand\thetable{\thesection.\roman{table}} 
\pagestyle{plain}
\pagenumbering{Roman}
%\setcounter{page}{1} %% not needed

%% see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/33901/5001
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\dupcntr}[2]{%
    \expandafter\let\csname c@#1\expandafter\endcsname\csname c@#2\endcsname
}
\makeatother
\dupcntr{table}{figure}  % make one counter the duplicate of the other

\begin{document}

\appendix
\refstepcounter{section} % just for this example

\begin{table}[ht!]\caption{Table A}\label{tab:a}\end{table}
\begin{table}[ht!]\caption{Table B}\label{tab:b}\end{table}
\begin{figure}[ht!]\caption{Figure A}\label{fig:a} \end{figure}
\begin{figure}[ht!]\caption{Figure B}\label{fig:b} \end{figure}
\begin{table}[ht!]\caption{Table C}\label{tab:x}\end{table}

\end{document}
```