# Common numbering for figures and tables

Tags: floats, latex-base, chngcntr

How can I make a common numbering for my figures and tables?

For instance, I want to obtain in Section 1 something like: Table 1.1, Figure 1.2, Table 1.3, Table 1.4, Figure 1.5

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Slave duplicate counter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33898/5764); `\makeatletter\let\c@figure\c@table\makeatother`

Comment: @Werner Thx! It worked for me!

Comment: @Werner that does not really work for floats it makes figure and tables use the same counter but they will float out of order. I'm voting to re-open

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make the figure and table environments use the same counter simply by

```
\let\c@figure\c@table
```

But if you do that, they are still independent float types so they can float past each other resulting in the floats being numbered in arbitrary order, eg

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}


\makeatletter
\let\c@figure\c@table
\makeatother 
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[p]
  \centering
  
  \caption{ttttt}
\end{table}


zzzzz


\begin{figure}[t]
  \centering
  
ffff
   \caption{ffff}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

If you add

```
\let\ftype@figure\ftype@table
```

Then the figure environment will use the same float sequence as tables, so be kept in sequence.

## [image]

That may be enough, however the figures and tables will be listed separately showing "gaps" in the numbering as here:

[image]

```
\listoffigures

\listoftables
```

So you may prefer to use a combined list in `\listoftables` by using

```
\makeatletter
\let\c@figure\c@table
\let\ftype@figure\ftype@table
\let\ext@figure\ext@table
\renewcommand\listtablename{List of Tables and Figures}
\makeatother
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation!